# geojson /leaflet properties issue

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

im kind of new with geojson properties and leaflet js code.

This is a very simple question, but when I make the bindpopup in my marker the title of the geojson variable disappears so I only see the html tag content but no its title.

I wish to see in the pop up the title and under the title the popup content.

But as I said, title disappears. Here is the code and thx for your time:)

```
geojson = [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [data[i].longitude,data[i].latitude]
                        },

                "properties": {
                "title": "Emergencia: "+data[i].priority,
                "icon": {
                "iconUrl": data[i].imagen,
                "iconSize": [50, 50], // size of the icon
                "iconAnchor": [25, 50], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
                "popupAnchor": [0, -25], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
                "className": "dot"
                        }
                        }
                }];     //alert(data[i].longitude.valueOf());

                var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().setGeoJSON(geojson).addTo(map);     
                myLayer.on('layeradd', function(e) {
                var marker = e.layer,
                feature = marker.feature;
                marker.setIcon(L.icon(feature.properties.icon));

                var popupContent='<br><p>Id emergencia:'+data[i].id_emergency+'</p>'//IMPORTANTISIMO
                marker.bindPopup(popupContent,{
                closeButton: true,
                   minWidth: 150
                });


                });
                myLayer.setGeoJSON(geojson);
```

Comment: When you say that "the title of the geojson variable disappears," do you mean that the title is originally visible on the map, but then disappears to be replaced by `popupContent`? Or do you just mean that you want the popup to contain the title, but it does not? If the latter, you should simply place the title in `popupContent` before the other items you wish to display, i.e. `var popupContent='<b>' + feature.properties.title + '</b><br><p>Id emergencia:' + data[i].id_emergency + '</p>'`

Comment: well it was the first thing you said but you answered me putting the popup sentence, i didnt know that I have to use that structure "feature.properties.title". Thx a lot :)